# If F from V into U is a nonsingular linear map. Then the image of any linearly independent set is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Many thanks in advance for any help on this question!! it's really appreciated :).

The theorem I am grappling with is: if F from V into U is a nonsingular linear map. Then the image of any linearly independent set is linearly independent.

I have a proof for this theorem which is correct:

1. Take a linear combination of the $F(v_{i})$, $a_{1}F(v_{1})+a_{2}F(v_{2})+...+a_{n}F(v_{n})=0$.
2. Use the properties of linear maps to produce $F(a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n})=0$.
3. As F is nonsingular Ker(F)={$0$}, $a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n}=0$.
4. As {$v_{i}$} is linearly independent, ${a_{i}}=0$ and {$F(v_{i})$} is linearly independent.

I have another proof which I believe is incorrect: I would really appreciate help on this proof; please tell me where I have gone wrong.

1. Take a linear combination of the $v_{i}$, $a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n}=0$. As {$v_{i}$} is linearly independent, the ${a_{i}}=0$.
2. As F is a linear map, zero maps to zero and as $a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n}=0$, $F(a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n})=0$.
3. Use the properties of linear maps to produce $a_{1}F(v_{1})+a_{2}F(v_{2})+...+a_{n}F(v_{n})=0$.
4. As {$v_{i}$} is linearly independent, the ${a_{i}}=0$ and {$F(v_{i})$} is linearly independent.

I believe this is not correct as this does not rely on the map being nonsingular and would apply to singular linear maps also. I also know it is possible to have a linearly independent set in the domain and for its image to not be linearly independent.

Many thanks for any assistance :)

Comment: Do you mean _injective_ by nonsingular ?

Comment: Hi, non-singular means Ker(F)={0}. There is a theorem which says F is injective iff Ker(F)={0}. So non-singular implies injective. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of linear independence says $F(v_1),..F(v_n)$ are LI if $\sum a_i F(v_i)=0$ implies each $a_i=0$. So to prove linear independence you have to start with the equation $\sum a_i F(v_i)=0$. Starting with $\sum a_i v_i=0$ doesn't prove anything.

Comment: Thanks Kavi :). If I start with a linearly independent set in the domain, by the properties of linear maps the coefficients also equal zero in the image. This is the same logic as step 4 in the correct proof I posted. Could you please explain why starting in the domain doesn't work? Many thanks.

Comment: The on;y way to prove that a set of vectors LI is to start with a linear combination of **those vectors**, set it equal to $0$ and prove that the coefficients are all $0$. If you start with something else you are not proving LI.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The second "proof" is non-sense ! The correct proof has to start with:

"let $a_{1}F(v_{1})+a_{2}F(v_{2})+...+a_{n}F(v_{n})=0...... $".

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different (but possibly more enlightening) approach is to use the fact that if $F$ is non-singular then it has an inverse $F^{-1}$ which is also a linear map.

So if the image $F(X)$ of a set $X$ is *not* linearly independent, then $F^{-1}(F(X))$ will not be linearly independent either because $F^{-1}$ is linear. But $F^{-1}(F(X))=X$, so $X$ is not linearly independent.

Hence if $X$ is linearly independent then $F(X)$ is also linearly independent.

Comment: Thanks for this. However F can be nonsingular (therefore one-to-one) but not onto. I think your proof is correct if F is bijective. To have an inverse there must be a one-to-one correspondence (F must be bijective: both one-to-one and onto) between the domain and the image/codomain.

Comment: True. So $F^{-1}$ is only defined on the image $F(V)$. But $F(X)$ is contained in $F(V)$ so $F^{-1}(F(X))$ is defined.

Comment: I may be wrong here :), but from my perspective F still has to be onto in this example and this would not work if F is not onto. F(V) and F(X) are the same F and therefore if the F in F(V) is onto then the F in F(X) has to be onto, where X is a subset of V, as every element of the codomain is assigned to an element in the domain when onto. My first proof above works if the F in F(V) is not onto. I'd be happy to hear your thoughts.

Comment: $F:V \to U$ need not be onto, but $F:V \to F(V)$ and $F:X \to F(X)$ are onto by definition. Same $F$ in each case (unless you are very pedantic in how you define a function).

Comment: I have not come across this definition before (or is it a theorem considering its the same F?). What term can I search for so I can look into this further? Thanks very much for your help

Comment: You may be over-thinking this. $F(V)$ is simply the image of $V$ under $F$ i.e. $x \in V \iff F(x) \in F(V)$. So for each $y \in F(V)$ there is a $x \in V$ such that $y=F(x)$.

Comment: Many thanks this is perfectly clear :). On "will not be linearly independent either because $F^{-1}$ is linear." Are you using the theorem that if F is linear and a set F(X) is LI, then set X is LI which is proved by the properties of linear maps?  Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You proved that if $a_{1}v_{1}+a_{2}v_{2}+...+a_{n}v_{n}=0$. Then ${a_{i}}=0$

And this is a proof that the $v_i$'s are independent

(Whatever process you passed through doesn't count as long as it is true.)